# What prevents MSTest from running in parallel?

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

What can prevent MSTest from running in parallel? I set the parallelTestCount to 0, but it is still running one test at a time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possibility you may not have tried yet... This [article](http://blog.drorhelper.com/2010/03/vs2010-tip-how-to-run-unit-tests-in.html) mentions that you need to restart your environment before the changes will take effect. Also, have you made any changes to your testsettings before setting parallelTestCount to 0? If so you'd have to make the changes again. Hope this helps!

Comment: It is a vs2010 feature, how can I prevent it in vs2008?

Answer (score 3):

You must not have any data collectors configured and you cant run any Coded UI tests.

This [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/12/01/executing-unit-tests-in-parallel-on-a-multi-cpu-core-machine.aspx) contains all the details I think.

Answer (score 1):

Not having multiple cores. See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/12/01/executing-unit-tests-in-parallel-on-a-multi-cpu-core-machine.aspx).